# Looking for e-mail forwarding service (Mailgun is not an option)

Tags: email, sendgrid, mailgun, mailjet, email-forwarding

I'm looking for serious e-mail forwarding service (custom domain -> gmail).

At this moment I started integrating Mailgun service but many problems occurs.
Automation is impossible because Mailgun disables my domains preventively - that results messages are not delivered.

Now my account was disabled, also preventively and I can't do anything (just waiting for support - more than two hours and still waiting) - this is not acceptable and I can't provide my service based on Mailgun afraid that the customer will not receive any message sent to his domain in the future.

After testing Mailgun i dont believe in services like SendGrid or Mailjet but maybe I will?

API is required, service must be available for non-manual management.
Any alternatives for premium purposes?